# how to read a CSV file as resource using TextFieldParser

Tags: vb.net

I have a CSV file in my project resources which I want to read using `FileIO.TextFieldParser`

I tried `Dim parser = new TextFieldParser(My.Resources.ArticlesCSV)`, but since `TextFieldParser`  expects either a path (as string) or a stream, this is not working.
I guess one possibility is to convert the resource to a stream, but I cannot find how to do that...

What is the best way to get this working?

Comment: The `TextFieldParser` constructor does not expect a `Stream`.  A `StreamReader`, which is what would be passed most frequently, is not a `Stream`.  It is a `TextReader` that reads text from a `Stream`.  The `TextFieldParser` constructor will accept any `TextReader`.  As suggested in the answer by @AFriend, a `StringReader` is a `TextReader` that reads text from a `String`, so it is also acceptable.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am far from a VB guru, so I think missed something: I looked at the definition of FileIO.TextFieldParser and its constructur either needs `(path As String)` or `(stream As Stream)`  (both with optional encoding)...

Comment: Actually, we're both mistaken.  I just took another look and there are constructors that take a `String` path, a `Stream` and a `TextReader`.  I imagine that it requires a `TextReader` internally and, if you don't provide one, it creates a `StreamReader` and passes the `String` path or `Stream` that you provided on to that constructor.  In turn, the `StreamReader` requires a `Stream` so its constructor creates a `FileStream` if you pass a `String` path rather than a `Stream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new instance of [IO.StringReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) which is of type `TextReader` that `TextFieldParser` will accept. Just pass your CSV file (Thanks to AndrewMorton)

```
Using strReader As New IO.StringReader(My.Resources.ArticlesCSV)
    Using textparser As New TextFieldParser(strReader)
        textparser.Delimiters = {","}
        While Not textparser.EndOfData
            Dim curRow = textparser.ReadFields()
            ' Do stuff
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: btw: is it good practice to rewrite the first two lines to `Using textparser As New TextFieldParser(new StringReader(My.resources.ArticlesCSV))` ?

Comment: I think the `StringReader` would still be disposed when exiting the `Using` block and you shouldn't need to reference it for any reason as the work is being done by the `TextFieldParser`... It should be okay to do this, if it's more readable to you :)